# memory leak occurs when run the code which includes popen

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, popen

I am debugging simple popen code by using valgrind.

code popen_test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = popen("lsblk", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    pclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

command for compile

> gcc -g -O0 popen_test.c

command for run

> valgrind --tool=memcheck --num-callers=30 --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full ./a.out

log

> ==5993== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>   ==5993== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>   ==5993== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>   ==5993== Command: ./a.out
>   ==5993==
>   ==5994== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>   ==5994== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>   ==5994== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>   ==5994== Command: /bin/sh -c lsblk
>   ==5994==
>   ==5995== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>   ==5995== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>   ==5995== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>   ==5995== Command: /bin/lsblk
>   ==5995==
>   ==5995==
>   ==5995== Process terminating with default action of signal 13 (SIGPIPE)
>   ==5995==    at 0x4A971E4: write (write.c:26)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A43787: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.17 (fileops.c:1188)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A42B87: new_do_write (fileops.c:456)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A4482F: _IO_new_do_write (fileops.c:433)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A4482F: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.17 (fileops.c:430)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A44147: _IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.17 (fileops.c:136)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A36CE7: fclose@@GLIBC_2.17 (iofclose.c:53)
>   ==5995==    by 0x10EAEB: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A09CC7: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
>   ==5995==    by 0x4A09E2B: exit (exit.c:139)
>   ==5995==    by 0x49F5D27: (below main) (libc-start.c:342)
>   ==5995==
>   ==5995== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==5995==     in use at exit: 16,735 bytes in 10 blocks
>   ==5995==   total heap usage: 1,136 allocs, 1,126 frees, 2,262,873 bytes allocated
>   ==5995==
>   ==5995== 12,639 (12,456 direct, 183 indirect) bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
>   ==5995==    at 0x484A124: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)
>   ==5995==    by 0x114ED3: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==5995==    by 0x118153: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==5995==    by 0x10ED6B: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==5995==    by 0x10DC0F: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==5995==    by 0x49F5D23: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
>   ==5995==
>   ==5995== LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==5995==    definitely lost: 12,456 bytes in 3 blocks
>   ==5995==    indirectly lost: 183 bytes in 6 blocks
>   ==5995==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5995==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
>   ==5995==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5995== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>   ==5995== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
>   ==5995==
>   ==5995== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==5995== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>   ==5994==
>   ==5994== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==5994==     in use at exit: 1,075 bytes in 30 blocks
>   ==5994==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 2 frees, 1,211 bytes allocated
>   ==5994==
>   ==5994== LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==5994==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5994==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5994==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5994==    still reachable: 1,075 bytes in 30 blocks
>   ==5994==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5994== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>   ==5994== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
>   ==5994==
>   ==5994== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==5994== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>   ==5993==
>   ==5993== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==5993==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==5993==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 256 bytes allocated
>   ==5993==
>   ==5993== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>   ==5993==
>   ==5993== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==5993== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

I can see it leaks memory for popen.
Does my code have mistake ? or How to use valgrind is wrong ?
Would you give me any help ?

Thank you.

**Postscript**
I changed the code to avoid SIGPIPE.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char var[256] = {0};

    fp = popen("lsblk", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp) != NULL)
    {
        ;
    }

    pclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

> ==7778== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>   ==7778== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>   ==7778== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>   ==7778== Command: ./a.out
>   ==7778==
>   ==7779== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>   ==7779== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>   ==7779== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>   ==7779== Command: /bin/sh -c lsblk
>   ==7779==
>   ==7780== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>   ==7780== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>   ==7780== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>   ==7780== Command: /bin/lsblk
>   ==7780==
>   ==7780==
>   ==7780== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==7780==     in use at exit: 12,639 bytes in 9 blocks
>   ==7780==   total heap usage: 1,136 allocs, 1,127 frees, 2,262,873 bytes allocated
>   ==7780==
>   ==7780== 12,639 (12,456 direct, 183 indirect) bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
>   ==7780==    at 0x484A124: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:752)
>   ==7780==    by 0x114ED3: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==7780==    by 0x118153: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==7780==    by 0x10ED6B: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==7780==    by 0x10DC0F: ??? (in /bin/lsblk)
>   ==7780==    by 0x49F5D23: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
>   ==7780==
>   ==7780== LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==7780==    definitely lost: 12,456 bytes in 3 blocks
>   ==7780==    indirectly lost: 183 bytes in 6 blocks
>   ==7780==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7780==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7780==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7780==
>   ==7780== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==7780== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>   ==7779==
>   ==7779== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==7779==     in use at exit: 1,075 bytes in 30 blocks
>   ==7779==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 2 frees, 1,211 bytes allocated
>   ==7779==
>   ==7779== LEAK SUMMARY:
>   ==7779==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7779==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7779==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7779==    still reachable: 1,075 bytes in 30 blocks
>   ==7779==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7779== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>   ==7779== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
>   ==7779==
>   ==7779== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==7779== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>   ==7778==
>   ==7778== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==7778==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==7778==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 4,352 bytes allocated
>   ==7778==
>   ==7778== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>   ==7778==
>   ==7778== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==7778== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

SIGPIPE does not show up but it looks memory leak occurs on a popen process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your program (in process 5993) doesn't leak.

```
==5993== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5993== in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5993== total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 256 bytes allocated
==5993==
==5993== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

`lsblk` (in process 5995) still had memory allocated, but that's normal because the process was killed (by SIGPIPE) before the program completed.

```
==5995== Process terminating with default action of signal 13 (SIGPIPE)
```

A process receives a SIGPIPE signal when it writes to a closed pipe or socket. (`lsblk`'s stdout, in this case.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the code to avoid SIGPIPE but it looks memory leak occurs. Would you check a postscript ? Thank you.

Comment: Your program still doesn't leak. The other program does, but there's no reason to believe it has anything to do with `popen`.